# Exim not able to listen on port 465 or 587 for TLS connection

Tags: email, ufw, smtp, mta, exim

I am configuring Exim on a Ubuntu server to send and receive mails via TLS.

Followed many guides which shows on how to configure Exim with TLS but still my Exim doesn't listen on 465 or 587

Exim only listen's on port 25 and I am able to send an receive mails

This is the official guide that I followed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Exim4

But still no luck, also I cannot find any reference in the config files which indicates on which ports is exim listening

I have also allowed the ports 465 and 587 via ufw using the command:

```
ufw allow 465
ufw allow 465
```

The output of `exim -bP | grep "daemon_smtp_ports"` 
gives me the following

```
daemon_smtp_ports = smtp
```

after that i tried to add the following line `daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 587` in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` but it doesn't load it.

can anybody help me on why this is happening or are there any steps that I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem as I'm just a beginner with Linux. Been banging my head against the wall for hours today and following every single post about how to change the port.

Finally ended up modifying /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template (the original entry is commented out):

```
# listen on all all interfaces?
.ifdef MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
#local_interfaces = MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
local_interfaces = <;   [192.168.200.2]:465 ; \
                        [192.168.200.2]:587
.endif
```

Then did `sudo service exim4 restart` and got it working.

You can check if that helped with `ss -lntp | grep exim`

Answer (score 2):

At the end of **/etc/default/exim4** file there is:

```
# Options for the SMTP listener daemon. By default, it is listening on
# port 25 only. To listen on more ports, it is recommended to use
# -oX 25:587:10025 -oP /run/exim4/exim.pid
SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS=''
```

So set `SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS='-oX 25:465 -oP /run/exim4/exim.pid'` and restart exim4 service.